# Django Viewset detail supports only with pk? not args?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, url-routing

#### My ACTION view is not working.

## **How to pass args** not only pk?

I was using function based api like

## Function Based Api View (1)

```
{host}:{port}/api/food/<year>/<month>/<day>/
```

Now, I have new viewset for model **Food**.

## ViewSet (2)

```
{host}:{port}/food/
```

I hope to **integrate** this apis to one ModelViewSet so **i did like below**.

## **WHAT I WANT** (1) + (2)

```
{host}:{port}/food/files/<year>/<month>/<day>/
{host}:{port}/food/
```

## My Code

```py
class FoodViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Food.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [blahblah]
    authentication_classes = [blahblah]

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        return Response(blahblah)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        return Response(blahblah)

    @action(['GET'], detail=True)
    def files(self, request, year, month, day):
        ...
        return Response(blahblah)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I clear this problem with query url like below.

## URL

```
{host}:{port}/food/files/?year=2019&month=02&day=27
```

## MY CODE

```
@action(['GET'], detail=False)
def files(self, request):
    year = request.query_params.get('year')
    month = request.query_params.get('month')
    day = request.query_params.get('day')
```